# Multiple language in vue.js app

Tags: methods, dynamic, vue.js, multilingual

I am using the [following script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multilanguage) so as to have french and english in my application:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { MLInstaller, MLCreate, MLanguage } from 'vue-multilanguage';

Vue.use(MLInstaller);

export default new MLCreate({
  initial: 'english',
  save: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  languages: [
    new MLanguage('english').create({
      logo:'logo-english',
      emotion: happy,

    }),

    new MLanguage('french').create({
      logo:'logo-french',
      emotion: joyeux,

    })
  ]
})
```

For text I can simply do the following:

But for images I do not know how to retrieve the value of logo to pass it to my method below:

Method (dynamically pull the logo image and extension):

```
getImg(image, ext) {
  return require(`@/assets/images/${image:this.logo}.${ext}`);
},
```

Get the image:

I want to merge both and right now I can only get the alt value but cannot parse the `logo` one as I do not know how:

```
<img v-bind:src="getImg(logo, 'svg')" v-bind:alt="$ml.with('VueJS').get('logo')" />
```

How can I apply `$ml` to `"getImg(logo, 'svg')"`?

Comment: I'd suggest to edit the title to "How to handle images in multiple languages?". vue.js is already in the tags and your question is focused on images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed properties for that matter :

```
computed: {
    computerLogoName () {
        return this.$ml.with('VueJS').get('logo')
    }
}
```

But as you stated it, you want it to be dynamic, I'd use a technique which is like `mapGetters` in vuex :

First, in a separate file you need to create a function which will return an object containing all your getters. Like this :

```
export const mapLanguageKeys = function (keys) {
    let computed = {}

    for (let computedPropertyName in keys) {
        computed[computedPropertyName] = function mappedLanguageKey () {
            return this.$ml.with('VueJS').get(keys[computedPropertyName])
        }
    }

    return computed
}
```

So basically, this function takes an object in parameter. The key will be the name of the computed property (i.e. "computedLogoName"), and the value will be the "language key" (i.e. "logo"). Then, the code inside the function `mappedLanguageKey` is just the code that you would put inside your computed property.

The last step is to add these generated computed properties in your computed object. This is done with ES6's "..." operator (don't forget to import your function) :

```
computed: {
    ...mapLanguageKeys({
        'computedLogoName': 'logo'
    })
}
```

And this should do the trick.

Using it is now the easiest thing on earth, you have a computed property called `computedLogoName` which returns the "language value" for the "language key" `logo`. So in the javascript code you can just call  `this.computedLogoName` and in the html just `computedLogoName`.

How to put it in a separate file and import it :

Create a file called `language.js` (you can give it another name if you'd like). Then, paste the code of the function inside that file.
When you want to call that function in the component, you just need to import it like that :

```
import {mapLanguageKeys} from './path/to/language.js';
```

And you can use it.

Note : I am assuming you are using ES6.

Note 2 : You could also use a method.

Comment: Hey thanks Alex, is it possible to turn this into a method? I am new to vue so don't know how to call in external ES6 functions.

Comment: @HGB If you are familiar with ES6, this is not related to VueJS. However, I added a little explanation in my answer.
Note: I assumed you are familiar with your file structure. If you are not and if you are using vue-cli, you need to put it inside your `src` folder.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error which I presume is caused by the fact it is ES6 `mapLanguageKeys({
        'computedLogoName': 'logo'
    })` Gives me `Unexpected token (46:28)` with `45 |     mapLanguageKeys({
> 46 |         'computedLogoName': 'logo'
     |                             ^
  47 |     }),
  48 |   },
`

Comment: Did you put the `...` before the call to `mapLanguageKeys` as in the code in my answer ?

Comment: I no longer have an error Alex, See updated code. But the image does not translate upon clicking `<button
          v-for="lang in $ml.list"
              v-if="currentLang !== lang"
          :key="lang"
          @click="$ml.change(lang); currentLang = lang"
          v-text="lang"
      />` In fact nothing which comes part of your `mapLangugeKeys` gets translated, only loads the top language data.

Comment: Do you have vue tools for chrome installed ?

Comment: Yes, I have the event for the button: is `name:"vueml-language-changed"
type:"$emit"
source:"<Root>"
payload:Array[1]
0:"english"` But it does not change the value of `mapLanguagekeys` only the ones preceeded with `$ml.with` straight into my component.

Comment: Can you check that the value for the computer property `computedLogoName` is correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct Alex, `...mapLanguageKeys({
        'computedLogoName': 'logo',
    }),` That is why it picks up the English from data (see below) but the button does not translate it to french like with everything preceded by `$ml.list`. There is something in your function that is not making it dynamic. If you want to jump into slack to go through, let me know.

Comment: I meant check in vue tools: go to your component in vue tools and check that the value for the computed property `computedLogoName` has the correct value

Comment: Yes, it does: `computedLogoName:"bnc-english"` but like I said above, the button does not translate it. it just picks up the first language and stays like that unless you precede by the  `"$ml.with('VueJS')` so the dynamic function is not working.

Comment: Okay, that's weird, I will have a look and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks, let me know if you need to jump into a chat client

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED CODE:
**Language Data and multi language function**

```
//language.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import { MLInstaller, MLCreate, MLanguage } from 'vue-multilanguage';

Vue.use(MLInstaller);

export default new MLCreate({
  initial: 'english',
  save: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  languages: [
    new MLanguage('english').create({
      logo:'logo-english',
      emotion: happy,

    }),

    new MLanguage('french').create({
      logo:'logo-french',
      emotion: joyeux,

    })
  ]
})
```

**Code to make the image dynamic**

//tools.js

```
export const mapLanguageKeys = function (keys) {
    let computed = {}

    for (let computedPropertyName in keys) {
        computed[computedPropertyName] = function mappedLanguageKey () {
            return this.$ml.with('VueJS').get(keys[computedPropertyName])
        }
    }

    return computed
}
```

**Inside my component**

//header.js

```
<script>
import { MLBuilder } from 'vue-multilanguage'
import {mapLanguageKeys} from '../tools'
..


  computed: {
    ...mapLanguageKeys({
        'computedLogoName': 'logo',
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    changeLang(lang) {
      this.$ml.change(lang);
      this.currentLang = lang;
    },
    getImg(image, ext) {
      return require(`@/assets/images/${image}.${ext}`);
    },
  },
```

*My HTML call to the image and button switch*

```
    //Language placeholders
    <h1 v-text="$ml.with('VueJS').get('emotion')" />
    <img v-bind:src="getImg(computedLogoName, 'svg')" v-bind:alt="computedLogoName" />

   //Button switch
    <div class="tools">
      <button
          v-for="lang in $ml.list"
              v-if="currentLang !== lang"
          :key="lang"
          @click="$ml.change(lang); currentLang = lang"
          v-text="lang"
      />
```

Everything in `v-text` switches upon clicking the button, however the image itself `v-bind:src` only loads once and does not change again. I have tried adding `v-bind:src="lang"` to the button above but it still only loads the english logo.

Comment: you may conside add one computed property?

Comment: defined one computed property like `computedLogoName: function () {return this.$ml.with('VueJS').get('logo')}`, then inside the template, `<img v-bind:src="getImg(computedLogoName, 'svg')" v-bind:alt="computedLogoName" />`

Comment: I updated my answer above to make it more dynamic. I want to be able to pass any data placeholder, not just logo. But I am not doing it right as the image does not load.